# Sorting within each subgroup and summing first three values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and there are three columns, State_Name, County_Name, Population. Population is a numeric data. The question I want to answer is only looking at the three most populous counties for each state, what are the three most populous states. So I think first I need to groupby State_Name and County_Name. I can do that. But after that I am confused as to how to proceed. I am new to pandas, so guidance will help

Comment: Check other questions in pandas section to see how they display input/raw data and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some dummy data (please always include a sample of your data in the future).

```
State_Name,County_Name,Population
State1,State1_A,100
State1,State1_B,8000
State1,State1_C,75
State1,State1_D,876
State1,State1_E,2938
State2,State2_A,200
State2,State2_B,16000
State2,State2_C,75
State2,State2_D,876
State2,State2_E,5876
```

Let's set the index to be State_Name and County_Name, and select the 'Population' column so we return a multiindexed pandas.Series

```
df = pd.read_clipboard() # Could have done index_col=[0,1] here
df = df.set_index(['State_Name','County_Name'])
s = df.Population
```

Now you can do Series.groupby and then use [nlargest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) on that (wouldn't work on a dataframe, that's why I use a Series):

```
s.groupby(level='State_Name').nlargest(3)

State_Name  State_Name  County_Name
State1      State1      State1_B        8000
                        State1_E        2938
                        State1_D         876
State2      State2      State2_B       16000
                        State2_E        5876
                        State2_D         876
Name: Population, dtype: int64
```